# Mac doesn't read pytube package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytube

I've a problem while making a YouTube downloader with pytube. I installed the package with

```
pip3 install pytube
python3 -m pip install pytube
```

And I have python3 installed on my machine but when I check which Python version I'm using in the terminal within VS Code, it says Python **2.7**

This is my code

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = ('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
#link = input("please enter the video url: ")

link = YouTube(link)

print("the video title is:{}".fomrat(link.title))
```

And this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube-downloader.py", line 8, in <module>
    kick = YouTube(link)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 183, in prefetch
    self.js_url = extract.js_url(self.watch_html)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 143, in js_url
    base_js = get_ytplayer_config(html)["assets"]["js"]
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 202, in get_ytplayer_config
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="get_ytplayer_config", pattern="config_patterns")
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_ytplayer_config: could not find match for config_patterns
```

Answer (score 1):

1--> do you have python extension installed on your vs code ?
check this by tabbing the extension icon on the left of your screen
2--> make sure that there is no multiple python versions installed on your machine

Comment: 1. yes I have python extension installed on vs code.
2. on my machine python3 is installed but when i see what python version i have on the terminal of  VS code it says it is python 2.7

Comment: on the bottom left corner of your vs code try to see the version of python interpreter that is active , if it's python 2.7 click on it and choose python3

Comment: this error happens on both pycharm and VS code and yes python3 is active

Comment: you can try to install it from the terminal in the ide that you're using

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I have accidentally downloaded python 3.11 alpha release. (The version is incomplete, it can't be used like stable releases.)

But I can't get Mac to run the most recent stable release 3.10, since a newer version is already in the system.

I don't wanna delete the library folders.
So everytime I download a package or anything, I download it with the specific python version, and I make sure to run my preferred version in the IDE. That way you can work with a specific version.

ex ;
I downloaded pytube with the command,
**$ pip3.10 install pytube**

instead of,
**$ pip install pytube**

**'pip'** command downloads the pytube package to the default version that runs on your computer. **'pip3.10'** downloads the package to the specified version.

Usually, the most recent version is the one that's gonna run in on your computer if it's a Mac. In windows, I guess you can change it from the paths manually or something. (I'm not sure about windows, I use Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Please close the currently used terminal (click the "`Kill Terminal`" icon), then use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` (or click "Terminal", "New Terminal") to open a new VS Code terminal, and then use the command "python --version" (or "pip --version") Check the source of the currently used python or pip, and the module is installed in this python environment.

[image]

If the python3 environment has been selected in the lower left corner of VS Code, but the newly created terminal is still in python3, please make sure that the first python environment variable is this python3. The VS Code terminal uses the first python environment by default.

[image]

In addition, after setting the python environment variable, please reopen VS Code.